# Why a segmentation fault in feof()?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, feof

I have the following enum and struct:

```
enum Destination { unknown = 0, hosok, parlament, var };

struct Client
{
  char name[30];
  char email[30];
  char phone_num[11];
  int client_num;
  enum Destination destination;
  struct tm registration_date;
};
```

When I invoke the following method, it reads the first struct and print it's name, then I get a segmentation fault.

```
void list_clientss()
{
  FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
  if( f == NULL )
  {
    perror("Error");
  }
  struct Client client;
  while( !feof( f ) )
  {
    fread(&client, sizeof(struct Client), sizeof(struct Client), f);
    printf("Name: %s\n", client.name);
  }
  fclose(f);
}
```

What did I wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: Are you sure it's segfaulting in `feof`? Your `fread` call is wrong and you're trashing your stack. You should be calling `fread(&client, sizeof(struct Client), 1, f);`

Comment: You're ready _1_ record of type `struct Client`. Say `fread(&client, sizeof(struct Client), 1, f);`

Comment: when your f is NULL you still trying to use it

Comment: @Cornstalks You're right, my fread call was wrong. But now it prints the last record twice..

Comment: @MartinMagyar Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?

Comment: @MartinMagyar -- the last record is being printed twice because [you should never use `while (!feof(fp)) {}`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: Not that it's happening in your case but in general if you try to fopen() a file and it fails the program shouldn't just give a message and continue.  Use an exit(1) or something in this case.  And feof() on a file that didn't open wouldn't be pretty, might not give a segfault.  That's true of reading from a file that didn't open too, I've never used fread().

Comment: Oh, the duplicate line.  Try another test for feof( ) before you actually use the data you read.  The while loop may set it but not bail out in time.  And I use !feof() fairly often, nobody told me I shouldn't.

Comment: @AlanCorey  The have now:)   The 'Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?' Q&A, as linked by Bo, is the second question down in the C 'frequent' list.

Comment: Works fine as long as you test it again inside the loop before you actually use the data.  I usually and it with an strlen() check on what I read.  Being able to read a file until EOF is pretty basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, your fread calls should be as follows:

```
fread(&client, sizeof(struct Client), 1, f);
```

Secondly, instead of using `feof`, you might use the return value of `fread`. `fread` returns the number of elements to read that you have passed to it. You can check if this number is different than one. For example,

```
while (fread(&client, sizeof(struct Client), 1, f) == 1) {
    printf("Name: %s\n", client.name);
}
```

**Edit 1:** Update the while loop to more idiomatic and elegant version as **Weather Vane** suggested.

Comment: More idiomatic might be `while (fread(&client, sizeof(struct Client), 1, f) == 1) { printf("Name: %s\n", client.name); }`

Comment: Thanks! I used `feof` because we learnd it in university, but now I understand why it was bad.